# Changing text on input (not placeholder)

Tags: javascript, html

the idea is to change the text inside the *text input* with a button, but i cant get it to work even without it! just by pure code i want to set it to '123' but it wont change no matter what, clearly the problem is in the HTML but i dont seem to find it. Here's what im writing in JS :

```
let contraseña = document.getElementById("contraseñaGenerada");

contraseña.value = "123";
```

I also tried with the following but it didnt work either.

```
 contraseña.innerText = "123";
```

Here's the HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Password Generator</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<h1 class="Texto">Welcome to our password generator.</h1>
<h3 class="Texto">Use our free online generator to get access to a highly secure random password of your liking. Choose the characters you want on your password and let the generator do the rest.</h3>

<br><br><br>    

<h2 class="Texto">Customize your password.</h2>
<br>

<div id="divCentro"> 

    <input type="text" name="contraseñaGen" id="contraseñaGenerada" >

    <div id="botones">

        <button class="boton">Copy to clipboard.</button>
        <button class="boton">Generate again.</button>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="Caracteristicas">

        <div id="Izquierda">

            <label for="barritaRange" class="TextoChico">Longitud de la contraseña: <br></label>
            <input type="number" id="numeroLongitud"><input type="range" name="barrita" id="barritaRange">

        </div>

        <div id="Derecha">
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="FacilDecir">   
            <label for="FacilDecir" class="TextoChico" >Facil de decir.</label>   
            <input type="checkbox" id="Minus">        
            <label for="Minus" class="TextoChico" >Incluye minusculas.</label>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="Mayus">
            <label for="Mayus" class="TextoChico" >Incluye mayusculas.</label>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="Nums">
            <label for="Nums" class="TextoChico" >Incluye numeros.</label>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="Simbolos">
            <label for="Simbolos" class="TextoChico" >Incluye simbolos.</label>  

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost half an hour i realized its because my

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

was on the top instead of bottom of body, make sure to add it to the end.. omg.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set input value with `element.value` property

```js
let contraseña = document.getElementById("contraseñaGenerada");
contraseña.value = 'My Value';
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Password Generator</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<h1 class="Texto">Welcome to our password generator.</h1>
<h3 class="Texto">Use our free online generator to get access to a highly secure random password of your liking. Choose the characters you want on your password and let the generator do the rest.</h3>

<br><br><br>    

<h2 class="Texto">Customize your password.</h2>
<br>

<div id="divCentro"> 

    <input type="text" name="contraseñaGen" id="contraseñaGenerada" >

    <div id="botones">

        <button class="boton">Copy to clipboard.</button>
        <button class="boton">Generate again.</button>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="Caracteristicas">

        <div id="Izquierda">

            <label for="barritaRange" class="TextoChico">Longitud de la contraseña: <br></label>
            <input type="number" id="numeroLongitud"><input type="range" name="barrita" id="barritaRange">

        </div>

        <div id="Derecha">
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="FacilDecir">   
            <label for="FacilDecir" class="TextoChico" >Facil de decir.</label>   
            <input type="checkbox" id="Minus">        
            <label for="Minus" class="TextoChico" >Incluye minusculas.</label>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="Mayus">
            <label for="Mayus" class="TextoChico" >Incluye mayusculas.</label>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="Nums">
            <label for="Nums" class="TextoChico" >Incluye numeros.</label>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="Simbolos">
            <label for="Simbolos" class="TextoChico" >Incluye simbolos.</label>  

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```